# Modifying Patterns with SED

Tags: sed, wildcards

I was wondering if *sed* can be used to modify rather then to replace patterns by, for example, replacing the first character of the pattern. I'm working with text files that contain `AXYZ`, where `XYZ` are various three letter combinations. Is there a way to tell *sed* to change all `AXYZ` to  `XYZ`, by replacing `A` with an empty space  ?
--Mike

Comment: By "empty space" do you mean `""` - as in a zero-length string, or do you mean `" "` - as in a space character?

Comment: give sample input/output. what would be the result for example on a line like `Adws, AXYZ, Axsqw, Aza,`

Comment: By empty space I meant " ". For example I have AGLU, AASP, ALYS or AVAL, and I want to replace them with  GLU,  ASP,  LYS,  and  VAL, respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing group `(...)` for the three letter combination, i.e. `([A-Z]{3})` and use `\1` to refer to this (first) group in the replacement.

Example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' AGLU AASP ALYS AVAL | sed -E 's/A([A-Z]{3})/ \1/'
 GLU
 ASP
 LYS
 VAL
```

Comment: Thanks @Freddy, that did the job, but I had to add `g` to the command, otherwise it would substitute only the first matching pattern encountered per line:

    ```sed -E 's/A([A-Z]{3})/ \1/g' ```.

I got lucky here, and by restricting the letters in the range, I was able to replace the desired patterns. How can I do this with further restrictions on the three letter pattern? For example what if I wanted to replace only AASP and ALYS but not ATOM, AANP or AGLU?

Comment: Remove the bracket expression and use strings with alternation `|`, e.g. `sed -E 's/A(ASP|LYS)/ \1/g'`

Comment: That worked nicely! I tried `'s/A([(ASP)(LYS)]{1})/ \1/g'` but that didn't work (any comments why?).

Comment: Because the bracket expression matches a single character (one of `(`, `)`, `A`, `L`, `P`, `S`, `Y`) and the `{1}` is redundant in this case. You need to learn how regular expressions work.

Comment: I only recently started to learn linux and python. I'm trying to implement what I learned to actual useful (for me tasks) though sometimes I go overboard with this. Any online resources on regular expressions that you would recommend?

Comment: There are so many resources on the web, but I don't know any good ones with lots of  examples for beginners. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `sed` should work - if I understand what you actually want to do. Here's an example where a string (which could be a file name) containing the letter `A`. The SED *substitutions* below will replace the **first occurrence** of the letter `A` with `_`, `` (zero-length string), and , respectively.

```
$ SOMEFILE="AASP"  
$ echo $SOMEFILE
AASP
$ echo $SOMEFILE | sed "s/A/_/"
_ASP
$ echo $SOMEFILE | sed "s/A//"
ASP
$ echo $SOMEFILE | sed "s/A/ /"
 ASP
```